# FFmpeg does not convert .ts files to .mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, google-colaboratory, mp4

I am trying to run this code to convert a .ts file in my Google Colab to a .mp4 file:

```
import subprocess

infile = '/content/result/00000.ts'
outfile = '/content/result/video.mp4'

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', infile, outfile])
```

However, I don't see anything in `/content/result/` except the .ts files.  This is the output cell:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-i', '/content/result/00000.ts', '/content/result/video.mp4'], returncode=1)
```

Comment: What does the ffmpeg log, sent to stderr, say?

Comment: @Gyan What do you mean?

Comment: Log == ffmpeg's messages, sent to console. Add `-report` to your command if you can't obtain it. FFmpeg will generate a text file.

Comment: `/content/result/00000.ts: Invalid data found when processing input` I got this when I ran the ffmpeg command in a single cell

Comment: FFmpeg thinks the input isn't valid. Can you play it elsewhere?

Comment: I wonder if it's a encoding problem. @oo92 can you share the encoding format of  `00000.ts`?

Comment: @dravit How can I do that?